# How to update multiple records on a nested recordsets in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Help! I have a nested recordsets namely questions and answers and a corresponsing checkbox for each question. How can I update multiple values in a recordset? shall i loop the Update query? Any help would be extremely appreciated.

here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_iexam, $iexam);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM exam_questions WHERE question_exam_id = '$exam_id'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $iexam) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

do { ?>
    <tr>
        <th width="170" scope="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
                   value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['question_id']; ?>"/>
            Question:
        </th>
        <td colspan="2" scope="col">
            <input name="textfield" type="text"
                   value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['question_description']; ?>"
                   size="50"/></td>
        <td width="549" colspan="2" scope="col"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Answers:</td>
    <?php
    mysql_select_db($database_iexam, $iexam);
    $query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM exam_answers WHERE answer_question_set_id = '" . $row_Recordset1['question_id'] . "'";
    $Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $iexam) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Recordset2       = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
    $totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

    do { ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="170">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input name="textfield2" type="text" size="20"
                       value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['answer_description']; ?>"/>
                <input
                    name="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['answer_question_set_id']; ?>"
                    type="radio"
                    value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['answer_iscorrect']; ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, loop the update query

Answer (score 0):

You can set checkbox name like name="checkbox[]" for question_id and name="textfield[]" for question_description and finally when you submitted this form you will get a array of this records then you set a for-loop to get separate value and update it into database or any where

Comment: how? I dont a idea how to deal with this.